# Magento2 Remove all password validation

Tags: magento2, validation

I've tried removing `data-validation` Tag from password input but it didn't work for Reset Password, New Password, and Change Password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a file `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/mage/validation.js`

And modified following function and return true.

```
validate-customer-password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable password validation from the admin panel for that
got to `Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration` in `Password Options`  section there is a field `Number of Required Character Classes` set `1` in that field and in `Minimum Password Length` set `1` and save the configuration.

Now it will accept any 1 character in password.

Comment: Check question heading  "Remove all password validation". And I think he just try to remove the data-validation attribute to remove password validation that's why I have suggest this way instead of removing data-validation attribute.